# writing unicode characters to Database using ODBC in MFC Application

Tags: database, visual-c++, mfc, odbc

I have connected to a database using ODBC in an unicode MFC Application and I am filling the database with some unicode data with the CDatabase::ExecuteSQL(CStringW ...) like below:

```
CStringW sSql;
sSql.Format(L"INSERT INTO Reports ( %s, '%s')", sField1, sValue1);
m_db.ExecuteSQL(sSql);
```

but what i actually write into database is some ? characters instead of unicode ones.
Is there any solution to this.
Regards

Comment: Dumb question, but are you sure it's a unicode column that you're trying to insert?

Comment: How could I make sure about it or how could make a column unicode

Comment: I've been away from SQL for a year so I don't remember, but I'm sure its pretty easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your database field is of type NVARCHAR(x).